# Installing a platform driver

Tags: drivers, kernel-modules, devices

I have recently acquired a device driver for an integrated watchdog timer on a x86 board on which I am running a minimal Linux system. The kernel is 3.6.11 and it has been built using `buildroot`.

My installation does not run `udev` so I am required to manually perform an `insmod` and `mknod` for any drivers that I require. I have managed to do this for a CAN driver, but for this watchdog driver, I am able to cross-compile the source code for the target and I am successfully able to `insmod` the resulting .ko file. After this there are no errors generated and a call to `lsmod` reports that the module is loaded.

The problem I am having is that I need to created a device node in `/dev` for this driver and I am not sure how to proceed. I do not know how to obtain device major and minor numbers like I can for char devices.

The source of this driver suggests it is a platform device driver but I am not sure what that even means. I have only heard of character and block devices and so – is the notion of major and minor numbers relevant to platform devices? If so, how can I obtain this information? There is no entry within `/proc` for this device driver name and I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: This file describes the currently allocated major and minor device number for the 2.6+ kernel. I'm quite surprised it's so old, by the way. http://www.lanana.org/docs/device-list/devices-2.6+.txt. This file is also available in /usr/src/linux/documentation/devices.txt (assuming /usr/src/linux is the directory where your kernel sources are installed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it uses the normal kernel watchdog interface, that's at `/dev/watchdog`, which is 10, 130 here.

It may also export another one (`/dev/watchdog0`, etc.). You can find that by querying sysfs:

```
$ cat /sys/class/watchdog/watchdog0/dev
253:0
$ cat /sys/class/watchdog/watchdog0/uevent 
MAJOR=253
MINOR=0
DEVNAME=watchdog0
```

And indeed:

```
$ ls -l /dev/watchdog0 
crw------- 1 root root 253, 0 May 17 18:26 /dev/watchdog0
```

That number may be dynamically allocated (I'm not sure), so it could be different on your machine.

(Platform devices probably also have something in `/sys/devices/platform`, which may let you set various parameters)

**edit:** You can create a character device with `mknod` like this (as root):

```
mknod -m 0600 /dev/watchdog c 10 130
```

`-m` sets the mode (file permissions, you have to use octal here); `/dev/watchdog` is the name; `c` means its a **c**haracter device (as opposed to **b**lock); 10 is the major number; 130 is the minor.

Comment: Thanks for this - yes the insmod has created an entry in /sys/class/misc/watchdog . The misc seems to refer to the device major of 10 and so now I have all I need to know to create a node with mknod. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @mathematician1975 I've added in an example `mknod` to my answer. You actually get the major and minor numbers from `/sys/class/misc/watchdog/dev` (or `…/uevent`). But I think 10:130 is statically allocated, so you can just hard-code that.